# PromQL : Using wildcards in metric names for topk

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I am sending Metrics to Prometheus and I am able to visualize their values using `PromQL` in Grafana. Here's an example:

```
topk(1, package_class_method_mean{domain="my_domain", asset="my_asset"})
```

Now, this shows me the graphs fine. However, what I want to do is to sort all the metrics in descending order of `mean`, something like:

```
topk(10, *_mean{domain="my_domain", asset="my_asset"})
```

How can I do that using `PromQL`?

**Edit**

I have tried the below query:

```
topk(10, {__name__=~"_mean"}{domain="my_domain", asset="my_asset"})
```

However, that gives me `ParseException` saying unexpected `{` in the aggregation.

Answer (score 11):

Use the following:

```
topk(10, {__name__=~".*_mean", domain="my_domain", asset="my_asset"})
```